# How can I simulate CallStateChange

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I have `PhoneStateListener` with `onCallStateChanged`.
I tried several actions in order that `onCallStateChanged` will be called:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
intent.putExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE, TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

But both ways doesn't make the desired result.
Is there a way (programatically) that I can do to make the `onCallStateChanged` be called?

Answer (score 0):

Try that on Toggle Button,

```
tb.setOnClickListener(new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("main_state", tb.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

Also call Method of onCallStateChanged,

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
    if (arg1) {
        edit.putBoolean("main_state", arg1);


    } else {
        edit.putBoolean("main_state", arg1);

    }
    edit.commit();
}
```

Also i have doing something like That,,

```
Handler ha = new Handler();
    ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService("activity");
            List<RunningTaskInfo> list_running = mActivityManager
                    .getRunningTasks(2147483647);
```